# App Store link using itms-apps: for developer portfiolio

Tags: ios, url, app-store, itunes

I can open up a page for an app review using the itms-apps:// scheme.

`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/xx/app/id000000000&action=write-review`

I have not been able to find a list of possible "action" parameters, other than 'write-review.'

Is there one to show the developer's portfolio?

I would like to direct a customer to my portfolio, but if I use...

`https://appstore.com/AbrahamStolk`

...[as suggested](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1633/_index.html) by Apple, then I get an intermediate dialog asking the user if she wants to open the app store, instead of a direct link.

Comment: I think it's working... It's taking it to the Developer page i.e. your page but it will always do it within iTunes on Mac, Windows, and iOS.

Comment: That latter link takes me to the developer page, but only after a confirmation from user. The itms-apps link, however, opens up the store without requiring user confirmation. That's why I prefer a better link than the AppStore.com one.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280218/what-is-different-between-itms-vs-itms-apps-when-opening-url-from-device. I don't think what you are looking for is possible with 'itms-apps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out you can do this with itms-apps, but you don't need an action parameter for it. Instead, you build a URL similar to this:

itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/abraham-stolk/id303320757

To find your developer id, you can use the [iTunes Link Maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com).

The use of itms-apps: instead of https: will cause a direct link to the app store, without going through the Safari browser first.